# Wordpress file upload succeeds under nginx but attempting to load the file returns 403

Tags: nginx, centos7, wordpress, file-permissions

I've been trying to debug this for the last few hours and, having solved so many issues already, I seem to have hit a brick wall

I have a Wordpress install using nginx under CentOS7 (AWS Lightsail if that matters). For this I have ensured

- `wp-content/uploads` directory is 766
- the directory owned by `apache:apache` and both nginx and php-fpm run under that user
- seLinux is `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` for the directory

That got me as far as uploading files successfully. It creates the file and the above permissions propagate properly (`ln -Z` and running `stat` as the `apache` user). Files are 666, but 766 doesn't seem to change anything. The older files I manually put up serve properly. The only difference I can find is the manually uploaded files are set in seLinux as

```
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

While the new 403 file is

```
Context: system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

I tried `setenforce 0` but no change. Restarted nginx as well and still no change. Logged error is

```
2019/05/19 22:35:06 [error] 21393#0: *4010 open() "/usr/share/nginx/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/file.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.69.44.142, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/file.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

Yet `/usr/share/nginx/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/another_file.jpg` works fine, so it doesn't seem related to the nginx config either.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the permissions. 766 is not a valid mode for a directory, at least not if you want to access the files within it.

Comment: Couple of problems, though. 1. The other working directories are just fine with 766. 2. Neither 755, nor 644, nor 777 fixes the problem. I have noted if I SCP new files into those directories, they don't work either

Comment: OK, well, you have even more serious permission problems than you let on initially. Fix them all.

Comment: Turns out 755 was the answer after all. Cloudflare was caching things, which was confusing. I bypassed it and was able to figure that out finally.

Comment: @Machavity I suppose 777 is the same as 755 + 022, not really understand why it doesn't work. BTW, the top Google search for SELinux is how to disable it.